# Moment/mgf of cosine of directional vectors?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, circular-statistics, moment-generating-function

Can anybody suggest how I can compute the second moment (or the whole moment generating function) of the cosine of two gaussian random vectors $x,y$, each distributed as $\mathcal N (0,\Sigma)$, independent of each other? 
IE, moment for the following random variable

$$\frac{\langle x, y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$$

The closest question is [Moment generating function of the inner product of two gaussian random vectors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699/moment-generating-function-of-the-inner-product-of-two-gaussian-random-vectors) which derives MGF for the inner product. There's also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263294/second-moment-of-cosx-y-for-normal-x-y) answer from mathoverflow which links this question to distribution of eigenvalues of sample covariance matrices, but I don't immediately see how to use those to compute the second moment.

I suspect that second moment scales in proportion to half-norm of eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ since I get this result through algebraic manipulation for 2 dimensions, and also for 3 dimensions from guess-and-check. For eigenvalues $a,b,c$ adding up to 1, second moment is:

$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^{-2}$$

Using the following for numerical check

```
val1[a_, b_, c_] := (a + b + c)/(Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c])^2
val2[a_, b_, c_] := Block[{},
  x := {x1, x2, x3};
  y := {y1, y2, y3};
  normal := MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, ( {
      {a, 0, 0},
      {0, b, 0},
      {0, 0, c}
     } )];
  vars := {x \[Distributed] normal, y \[Distributed] normal};
  NExpectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars]]

  val1[1.5,2.5,3.5] - val2[1.5,2.5,3.5]
```

Checking the formula for 4 variables (within numerical bounds):

```
val1[a_, b_, c_, 
  d_] := (a + b + c + d)/(Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c] + Sqrt[d])^2
val2[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Block[{},
  x := {x1, x2, x3, x4};
  y := {y1, y2, y3, y4};
  normal := 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {{a, 0, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0, 0}, {0, 0, c, 0}, {0, 0, 0, d}}];
  vars := {x \[Distributed] normal, y \[Distributed] normal};
  NExpectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars]]

val1[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5] - val2[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Comment: Due to rotational freedom, since the cosine is invariant under rotations, one of the vectors can be assumed to be a unit vector in whatever direction is most convenient. That should simplify the problem quite a bit, to the second moment of the cosine of $x \in \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ with respect to $(1,0,0,\ldots)$. EDIT: Actually, this depends on the symmetry of $\Sigma$.

Comment: w huber's answer here may be of interest: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85977/37483

Comment: @Student001  indeed, the 1/n rate derived in that question seems to be a special case of this formula, since we remove a degree of freedom by normalizing trace of covariance matrix to 1

Comment: Aside: Note that, wlog, $\Sigma$ is diagonal.

Comment: I found the question of the distribution of $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ being asked at least 3 times on crossvalidated, so hopefully this post will popularize the notion of "projected normal distribution" so it is no longer a question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hey Yaroslav, you really do not have to hurry accepting my answer on MO and are more than welcomed to ask further details :).*

Since you reformulate the question in 3-dim I can see exactly what you want to do. In MO post I thought you only need to calculate the largest cosine between two random variables. Now the problem seems tougher.

**First,** we calculate the normalized Gaussian $\frac{X}{\|X\|}$, which is not a trivial job since it actually has a name "projected normal distribution" because we can rewrite the multivariate normal density $X$ in terms of its polar coordinate $(\|X\|,\frac{X}{\|X\|})=(r,\boldsymbol{\theta})$. And the marginal density for $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ can be obtained in $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}f(r,\boldsymbol{\theta})dr$$

> An important instance is that in which $x$ has a bivariate normal
> distribution $N_2(\mu,\Sigma)$, in which $\|x\|^{-1}x$ is said to have a
> projected normal (*or angular Gaussian or offset normal*) distribution.[Mardia&Peter]p.46

In this step we can obtain distributions $\mathcal{PN}_{k}$ for $\frac{X}{\|X\|}\perp\frac{Y}{\|Y\|}$, and hence their joint density $(\frac{X}{\|X\|},\frac{Y}{\|Y\|})$ due to independence. As for a concrete density function of projected normal distribution, see [Mardia&Peter] Chap 10. or [2] Equation (4) or [1] . (Notice that in [2] they also assume a special form of covariance matrix $\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\Gamma & \gamma\\
\gamma' & 1
\end{array}\right)$)

**Second,** since we already obtained their joint density, their inner product can be readily derived using transformation formula $$\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|},\frac{Y}{\|Y\|}\right)\mapsto\frac{X}{\|X\|}\cdot\frac{Y}{\|Y\|}$$. Also see [3].

As long as we computed the density, the second moment is only a problem of integration.

**References:**

[Mardia&Peter]Mardia, Kanti V., and Peter E. Jupp. Directional statistics. Vol. 494. John Wiley & Sons, 2009.

[1]Wang, Fangpo, and Alan E. Gelfand. "Directional data analysis under the general projected normal distribution." Statistical methodology 10.1 (2013): 113-127.

[2]Hernandez-Stumpfhauser, Daniel, F. Jay Breidt, and Mark J. van der Woerd. "The general projected normal distribution of arbitrary dimension: modeling and Bayesian inference." Bayesian Analysis (2016).
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ba/1453211962

[3][Moment generating function of the inner product of two gaussian random vectors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51699/moment-generating-function-of-the-inner-product-of-two-gaussian-random-vectors)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Hopefully this is well worth your bounty!

Comment: The answer I posted on MO is not exactly what the OP wanted because I was thinking that he is searching for the canonical angle. my bad.

Comment: Could you provide a proof that assuming identity covariance matrix is w.l.o.g? It's not obvious to me. It's "easy" to show cardinal's claim that diagonal matrix is w.l.o.g, but how do you get rid of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Student001 If $\Sigma=P'\Lambda P$, then $PX$  have an identity covariance matrix.

Comment: Even if we assumed only diagonal covariance, it only makes the projected normal distribution scaled on main axes and hence introduce only scalars into the density of $\mathcal{PN}_k$. And [Mardia&Peter] does not assume anything on the covariance matrix as I can see in the quote. Assuming identity means the projected image lies on a sphere which makes it easier to visualize.

Comment: No, if $P'\Lambda P$ is the spectral decomposition of $\Sigma$, then $PX$ as covariance matrix $\Lambda$, which need not be the identity, so at least that step doesn't justify $\Sigma = I$ w.l.o.g. Maybe your last comment does, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Student001 Maybe I should use better notation but I mean square root decomposition.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix

Comment: so ... do you think my formula extends to more than 3 dimensions?

Comment: Ah, OK. So $P$ is symmetric but not orthogonal then? If $PP = \Sigma$, you still seem to claim that $(Px)^TPy / \sqrt{x^TPPx y^TPPy} = x^T\Sigma y / \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x y^T \Sigma y} = x^Ty / \sqrt{x^Tx y^Ty}$, where $x$ and $y$ are indep. $N(0, I)$ and the last equality is in distribution. Could you provide a proof of this?

Comment: @Student001 I carouse the answer again, I think the first step is actually not necessary because the projected normal density is in its closed form for any form of $\Sigma$. So the answer only involves calculation of $\mathcal{PN}_k$ and a transformation formula. I do not see why orthogonality is important here...Thanks for your carefulness and can you see if the answer is clear to you now?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov No, and I think its closed form involves a hypergeometric function according to my primary computation on bus. The projected normal distribution requires a bit complex technique than polar coordinates than [Mardia&Peter] claimed in 2-dim. Derivation is discussed in another post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91303/how-to-derive-the-projected-normal-distribution

Comment: ah, so the nice formula for 3 dimensions is just a coincidence? That's unfortunate

Comment: btw, I checked the formula for 4 variables numerically (code in answer), and it is still within error boundaries (although Mathematica reported error boundaries for NIntegrate get quite large, 0.38)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It is hard to say whether it is a coincidence without a neat calculation. It could be a conincidence or there is a deeper theoretical link that I do not know. Is mathematica doing symbolic calculation? (Sorry I know little about the computational side of stat beyond R.)