# Computing $E[yy'Cyy']$ for normalized Gaussian $y$

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose $x\sim \text{Normal}(0,\Sigma)$ with diagonal $\Sigma$.

Is there a closed form solution or a good approximation to the following quantity where $y=x/\|x\|$:

$$f(C)=E[yy'Cyy']$$

Target is to understand the growth rate of $g(k)=\operatorname{Tr}(\underbrace{f\circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{k} \circ I)$ in terms of $k$.

For unnormalized $x$, I can use Wick's theorem, and this iteration nicely factors, giving nice formulas for $g(k)$.

Wondering if there's a trick I can use to make it work for $y$.

Motivation: factoring density of $x$ is used in Bordelon [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02713) to give loss curve of SGD. Extending this to $y$ will transfer this analysis to the Kaczmarz method.

Comment: What do you know about $C$?

Comment: C0 is identity matrix and C1=f(C0). (Diagonal perhaps?). So these are two main cases I need to solve